# How can I learn Oracle JDeveloper?

Tags: jdeveloper

How can I start programming in Oracle jdeveloper? I have a good understanding of concepts in Java and I have worked in Netbeans 6.8 IDE, but how to practice in JDeveloper? Is it difficult to begin on it ?

I have a book of JDeveloper and tried more than once but  failed.

Answer (score 2):

Are you planning to learn how to use the IDE only or do you want to learn ADF?

If you want to learn the JDeveloper IDE, the best way is to install JDeveloper and... start writing some Java Code! The embedded help is pretty good but if you face any issues, the place to ask questions is the [Oracle JDeveloper and ADF Forum](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=83).

If you plan to learn ADF, please refer to the [Oracle JDeveloper and ADF Documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/documentation/index.html) page which contains LOTS of information. Start by checking out/running/tweaking the [sample applications built with JDeveloper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/index-098948.html), then proceed by reading the [Java EE Developer's Guide for Oracle ADF](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e16272/toc.htm). There are a number of nice [blogs on ADF](http://wiki.oracle.com/page/ADF+Blogs), such as [Dive into ADF](http://blogs.oracle.com/smuenchadf/) and [Shay Shmeltzer's blog](http://blogs.oracle.com/shay/) where you can find some topics for all levels (beginner to advanced). And again, visit the [Oracle JDeveloper and ADF Forum](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=83) for any questions you may have on ADF.

Hope this helps!